# linux equivalent command for FindExecutablePath

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets

I want to check in linux( redhat 6.4 ) whether browser is installed and if installed i want to launch a help document(.html files) in browser. Otherwise i want to launch help document in pdf.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this above scenario in C++ , wxwidgets.

Answer (score 1):

See [Launching the Default Browser](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Launching_The_Default_Browser) on the wxWidgets Wiki which provides an example of using the [wxFileType](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_type.html) class and [GetOpenCommand](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_type.html#a8f9858233c0cb06a2b87a8cd5861deb1)().

There is also [wxLaunchDefaultApplication()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__misc.html#ga04038d4c78e4c111d018b8f82b2d66c3) and [wxLaunchDefaultBrowser()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__misc.html#ga3ff36fe489da2a779248b56f283615ca).